# Прочитать метаданные с pdf построчно без дополнительных инструментов

Tags: delphi

Есть *pdf*, там есть поле метаданных «*/NC_ID(*». В блокноте я его вижу.
Думаю, дай я его прочту как *txt*, и поиском найду «/NC_ID(»

```
var
  LFileCertificate: TextFile;
  LIndex, L_Length, LInd: integer;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
  AssignFile(LFileCertificate, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(LFileCertificate);
  while not Eof(LFileCertificate) do
   begin
   Readln(LFileCertificate, S);
    if Pos('/NC_ID(', S) <> 0 then
    begin
      LInd := Pos('/NC_ID(', S);
      showmessage(Copy(S, LInd, 20));
      abort;
    end;
   //ShowMessage(S);
   end;
   ShowMessage('close file');
   CloseFile(LFileCertificate);
  end;
end;
```

та не тут то было,
Данное поле находит, но при условии, что я в блокнете половину данных удалю, а мне это не подходит.
Почему «*pos*» не срабатывает на полном файле. Максимальная длинна «*string =2 Гб*». Этот параметр находится в конце файла.

Comment: Сейчас бы двоичные файлы через ReadLn / Eof читать. Читайте нормально через TFileStream блоками и там уже ищите. Причём /NC_ID - в какой кодировке там хранится?.. Ansi / UTF-8, UTF-16, ещё какой?

Comment: кодировка UTF-8

Comment: Если метаданные в конце хранятся, неужели там нет  никакого заголовка в начале, который указывает на смещение меты от начала файла? (хз как пдф внутри устроен)

Comment: var
  

    FSO: TFileStream;
      s: string;
      q: ansistring;
      p: pansistring;
      LInd, LInd1:integer;
      BufferTB: TBytes;
      Buffer: PByte;
    begin
      FSO:=TFileStream.Create('d:\ex2.pdf', fmOpenRead);
      LInd:=FSO.Size;
      SetLength(s,LInd);
      FSO.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
      FSO.Read(Pointer(s)^,LInd);
      FSO.Free;
      LInd1 := Pos('/NC_ID(', s);
    ...

почему-то в "s" - все время фигня пишется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось с функцией `System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllText`